# use dotnet 5 Library in dotnet framework

Tags: .net, .net-core

I'am wondering if it is not possible to use a class library created with dotnet 5 in an Windows Forms app which uses .net Framework 4.8.

I tried several combinations for the library (dotnet 5, dotnet core 3.1) and the Windows Forms App (.net Framework 4.7.2, .net Framework 4.8) but i was unsuccessful every time. I always received the error message `CS1705` saying that the `System.Runtime` versions are not the same (see the full error message below).

```
Schweregrad Code    Beschreibung    Projekt Datei   Zeile   Unterdrückungszustand
Fehler  CS1705  Assembly "LibCloudCopy" mit Identität "LibCloudCopy, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" verwendet "System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" mit einer höheren Version als die referenzierte Assembly "System.Runtime" mit Identität "System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".  WinFormsUiTest  C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\WinFormsUiTest\WinFormsUiTest\Form1.cs    47  Aktiv
```

is there a way to bring dotnet 5 and .net Framework 4.8 together?

Thank you and regards
Andi

Comment: It's not possible. .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5. If you want to share code between .NET Core and .NET Old you'll have to target .NET Standard 2.0, which *doesn't* contain any of the Winforms/WPF classes included in .NET Core 3 and later

Comment: BTW this is nothing new. It's very well documented, explained and repeated in all tutorials, courses, classes and blog posts. You'll have to migrate the .NET Old application to .NET 5 to use any new Winforms features and fixes

Comment: Thank you, it can be so easy. Now I use .NET 5 for the Winforms application too.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. This will help you. You need to understand the .net standards. Official Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

If your library is written in one particular .net standard, then you can find the corresponding supported .net, .net core or .net framework etc.

Answer (score -1):

It is not doable. But i think you can reuse the code (C#) and you might get compile issues that need to be fixed before you can make the app up and running.